# How to integrate Google Ads Manager (GAM) using Google App Script

Tags: google-apps-script, oauth-2.0, integration, google-oauth

I need to create an integration between the API of GAM and the Google App Script. To do this, I have only the JSON with the credentials, in this format:

```
{
  "type": "service_account", 
  "project_id": "...", 
  "private_key_id": "...", 
  "private_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----...-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n", 
  "client_email": "...", 
  "client_id": "...", 
  "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth", 
  "token_uri": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token", 
  "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs", 
  "client_x509_cert_url": "..."
}
```

At the moment I'm trying to create the OAuth 2.0 with the information from the credential:

```
const auth  = OAuth2.createService("GAM")
        .setAuthorizationBaseUrl(credential.auth_uri)
        .setTokenUrl(credential.token_uri)
        .setPrivateKey(credential.private_key)
        .setIssuer(credential.client_email)
        .setClientId(credential.client_id)
        .setPropertyStore(PropertiesService.getScriptProperties())
        .setParam('access_type', 'offline')
        .setScope(['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/dfp']);
```

And using the "UrlFetchApp.fetch" to do the request to API:

```
 const url = "https://dns.googleapis.com/dns/v1/projects/" + credential.project_id;

 const options = {
  'method' : 'get',
  'contentType': 'application/json',
   headers: {
      Authorization: 'Bearer ' + getToken
   },
   'muteHttpExceptions': true,
 };

 const response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
 const data = response.getContentText();
```

I'm trying to do it this way, but I haven't got results yet and don't know what is wrong. If someone with knowledge using Google App Script and/or Google Ads Manager has any ideas or tips on how to do this integration.

Thanks

Comment: Are you getting anything in response or is it blank?

Comment: In general 403 status without authorization but sometimes is don't have the authorization scope, but all this is without modifying the code. And sometimes when the OAuth2 request for access is denied (false). I don't know if is my code or the API.